# Cómo hacer match entre dos array´s de objetos javaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando con array de objetos, y tengo la siguiente funcionalidad:
1.- A través de un servicio mandar a encriptar unicamente los valores de una propiedad de los objetos de cada elemento del array.
tengo un array en el que extraigo únicamente la propiedad que necesito de cada objeto

```js
 const array = [
      { nombre: 'Felix', apellidoP: 'Hernandez', edad: 25, valorEncriptar:'Hola como estas' },
      { nombre: 'Juan', apellidoP: 'Salazar', edad: 25, valorEncriptar:'Hola hola como estas' },
      { nombre: 'Abel', apellidoP: 'Abiel', edad: 25, valorEncriptar:'Hola qué haces' },
      { nombre: 'Hugo', apellidoP: 'Carlos', edad: 25, valorEncriptar:'Hola y adiós' }
    ]
```

Este es el código que llevo para extraer las propiedades y generar un nuevo array de objetos que mando a encryptar con esa estructura...

```js
 const newArray = array.map((value) => {
          let data = {}
          let valueEncrypt = value.valorEncriptar
          return data = {valueEncrypt}
        })

//Resultado
newArray = [
{valueEncrypt:'Hola como estas' },
{valueEncrypt:'Hola hola como estas' },
{valueEncrypt:'Hola qué haces' },
{valueEncrypt:'Hola y adiós' }
]
```

La respuesta del servicio de encryptado me responde con un array con los valores encriptados como el siguiente EJEMPLO:

```js
respuetaServicio = [
{valorEncriptado:'sxdfc´ryv_eedds94_' },
{valorEncriptado:'sxdfc*ryv_eedds94_' },
{valorEncriptado:'sxdfc]]]ryv_eedds94_' },
{valorEncriptado:'sxdfc***___ryv_eedds94_' }
]
```

Ahora lo que necesito es hacer match del array de encriptado con el array principal para agregar una nueva propiedad que se llame por ejemplo valor_encriptado, para que quede de la siguiente manera, pero garantizando que el valor de la propiedad sin encryptar si corresponda el valor de la propiedad encriptada

```js
const array = [
      { nombre: 'Felix', apellidoP: 'Hernandez', edad: 25, valorEncriptar:'Hola como estas', valor_encriptado:'sxdfc´ryv_eedds94_' },
      { nombre: 'Juan', apellidoP: 'Salazar', edad: 25, valorEncriptar:'Hola hola como estas', valor_encriptado:'sxdfc*ryv_eedds94_' },
      { nombre: 'Abel', apellidoP: 'Abiel', edad: 25, valorEncriptar:'Hola qué haces', valor_encriptado:'sxdfc]]]ryv_eedds94_' },
      { nombre: 'Hugo', apellidoP: 'Carlos', edad: 25, valorEncriptar:'Hola y adiós', valor_encriptado:'sxdfc***___ryv_eedds94_' }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sencillamente devuelve todos los valores del objeto inicial en el `map`, agregándole la nueva propiedad, así

```js
const array = [{
    nombre: 'Felix',
    apellidoP: 'Hernandez',
    edad: 25,
    valorEncriptar: 'Hola como estas'
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Juan',
    apellidoP: 'Salazar',
    edad: 25,
    valorEncriptar: 'Hola hola como estas'
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Abel',
    apellidoP: 'Abiel',
    edad: 25,
    valorEncriptar: 'Hola qué haces'
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Hugo',
    apellidoP: 'Carlos',
    edad: 25,
    valorEncriptar: 'Hola y adiós'
  }
]

const newArray = array.map((value) => {
  let valueEncrypt = "encriptado"+value.valorEncriptar;
  return { 
    ...value,
    valor_encriptado: valueEncrypt
  }
})

console.log(newArray);
```